# Induced map on simplicial homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map between topological spaces. Then we have an induced map on their singular homology groups $f_*: H_*(X) \rightarrow H_*(Y)$. The problem with these induced maps is that by going to singular homology in some sense you can't really see what's going on at the level of spaces. I'm wondering if there is a similar induced map on simplicial homology where you can more easily see what's going on?

Of course there might not be much hope for something like this since maps between spaces don't need to respect triangulations.

Comment: Perhaps you would like something like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_approximation_theorem?

Comment: You have given one reason behind the general argument of the paper at  arXiv:1610.07421 and published in Indagationes 2018. The emphasis is on filtered spaces, and in particular CW complexes with the cellular filtration. The tool is cubical homotopical methods, for reasonable  geometric grounds, as explained there, with references for the (substantial) details.